# Facebook Graph API - How do you retrieve the different size photos from an album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok, first off let me tell you I have no problems getting a user's photo album(s) and looping through the output to display all of the photos in the size I want.

However, if I want to call a photo like:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$this->session->page->photo_id?>/picture?access_token=<?=$this->session->member->facebook_access_token?>" />
```

I cannot figure out how to tell it the size I want it to show.

In this sample code from Facebook you will see that whey retrieving the album each photo in the array comes back with the different sizes in this sample array. I could just save the thumbnail url from this, but I don't want to store it, just retrieve when needed.

```
{
   "id": "10150146071831729",
   "from": {
      "name": "Facebook",
      "category": "Product/service",
      "id": "20531316728"
   },
   "picture": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash1/168119_10150146071831729_20531316728_7844072_5116892_s.jpg",
   "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash1/168119_10150146071831729_20531316728_7844072_5116892_n.jpg",
   "height": 483,
   "width": 720,
   "images": [
      {
         "height": 483,
         "width": 720,
         "source": "http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash1/168119_10150146071831729_20531316728_7844072_5116892_n.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 120,
         "width": 180,
         "source": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash1/168119_10150146071831729_20531316728_7844072_5116892_a.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 87,
         "width": 130,
         "source": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash1/168119_10150146071831729_20531316728_7844072_5116892_s.jpg"
      },
      {
         "height": 50,
         "width": 75,
         "source": "http://photos-g.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash1/168119_10150146071831729_20531316728_7844072_5116892_t.jpg"
      }
   ],
   ....... continued...
}
```

There has to be a way to retrieve these different sizes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Facebook provides a **type** option for the picture field, for example, you can specify something like:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture?access_token=yyy&type=normal />
```

where the type parameter can be one of *square*, *small*, *normal*, or *large* for profile pictures or *thumbnail*, *normal*, *album* for album pictures.

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ (under Connections section)

**Edit:** Added different options for album pictures

Comment: nope sorry. The type=(square,small,normal,large) is ONLY for profile pics and does not apply to Album Photos.

Comment: Oh oops, my bad, I misread the question. You could try type=(thumbnail,normal,album) though.

Comment: Was that a guess, because I've been digging around for a few hours and could not find this anywhere. type=album worked perfect, thanks.

Comment: It was a guess, I tried accessing an album photo with type=square and Facebook gave me an error with a list of valid types. I can't seem to find it in the documentation either...

Comment: Weird, I got nothing in return with valid types. Awesome. Facebook documentation is total crap. Thankfully the Graph is pretty easy to use.

Comment: Don't need the access token. `https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/picture?type=(small, normal, large, square)` works like a charm.

Comment: Note that it's now restricted to the following values: thumbnail, album or normal

Comment: Thumbnail and album are tiny.

Answer (score 7):

Thought I'd share a little trick in getting larger image sizes from the Graph API. Facebook as a little convention with image URLs that's not very obvious. For instance, take the following URL:

https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1/1185356_10201176263222205_1153673992_s.jpg

Notice the `_s.jpg` at the end? That determines the size of the image. You can change this to `_o.jpg` to get the "original" full size version. In other words, update the image URL to:

https://fbcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/t1/1185356_10201176263222205_1153673992_o.jpg

Every Facebook image has an `_o.jpg` version. Worst case, you get something the same size as the thumbnail. If that's the case, you're no better off than you were before.

Comment: somehow that isn't working for me, the pictures alway start with scontent and finishes with some sort of hash.  maybe they changed this?

Answer (score 0):

here src_big and src are different size image url source

```
    function get_photos_by_album_id($album_id){

 if($album_id)
     $fql            =   'SELECT pid,src_big,owner,link,position,created,caption,src      FROM photo WHERE aid="'.$album_id.'" ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,6';

            $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
        );
        $fqlResult   =   $this->facebook->api($param);
    return $fqlResult;

 }
```

Comment: Sorry, but OP said he wanted to use the graph API, not FQL. FQL is deprecated.

Comment: @fool4jesus were did you read that fql has been deprecated? i am currently developing with it and it works like a charm. i also couldnt find a post where they officially stated that

Comment: Maybe my bad. It is apparently a fairly common misconception since they address the question in this rather old post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/ . I may try this after all, because I don't have a satisfactory solution at present. Thanks!