# How to fetch FaceBook friends large image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

The image i am getting with this method is very small

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" 
                     andParams:[ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,id,name,link,gender,last_name,first_name",@"fields",nil]
                           andDelegate:self];
```

How to fetch the large image of friend with same method??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this link for your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629188/facebook-graph-api-how-do-you-retrieve-the-different-size-photos-from-an-album

Comment: @AnkitGupta okay , first of all i want use the same call as i mentioned above , i just want the bigger user profile image , means is there any parameter like picture_big like as we use in fql pic_big for fetching. I dont want to call another api to gets users big image

Comment: you dont need to fetch, its url is static. http://graph.facebook.com/[id]/picture?type=large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL of each image is returned as a string. You could modify the string by changing the last letter in the filename from "q" to "n", after having loaded it from facebook and before using it in any other way.

```
small image:         370412_xxxxxxxx_1715222999_q.jpg
medium/square image: 370412_xxxxxxxx_1715222999_s.jpg
large image:         370412_xxxxxxxx_1715222999_n.jpg
```

That would look something like this:

```
pictureUrl = [pictureUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_q.jpg"
                                     withString:@"_n.jpg"];
```

Comment: I've updated the answer to demonstrate what I meant. Just change the string after loading the list from FB. Seems there is no other way if you don't want to change the call.

Answer (score 0):

use `albums`,`photos` permission(size depend on upload time)

refer to this link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/