# Unable to vary the size of the image returned by ['picture'], Graph API for Facebook

Tags: php, css, facebook-graph-api

I use Graph API for Facebook to get my latest posts data and put them in a custom HTML page on my website.
In the JSON object returned by the API, there's an index 'picture' which designates the URL of an image attached to a Facebook post. Now Twitter's Rest API and Facebook's Graph API both propose **GET parameters to specify the size of the returned image** (small, large, thumbnail).

But while it works perfectly in Rest API, it just seems to be **ignored in Graph API**, as returned images are always **reduced compared to their real size**. I've tried different parameters, as documented in Graph API ([Facebook Graph API - How do you retrieve the different size photos from an album?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629188/facebook-graph-api-how-do-you-retrieve-the-different-size-photos-from-an-album)).

Here are some of my attempts:(Any should have worked, as of API)

```
'<img src='.$mypost['picture'].'>'
'<img src='.$mypost['picture'].'?type=large>'
'<img src='.$mypost['picture'].'?height=400&width=400'>'
```

in a HTML page, images returned are always small (about 150x150 the most time). I've tried different parameters, and it never changes anything.

I checked out my CSS and I'm sure there's no problem on that side, picture sizes are not overwritten by my side.

Link: http://spotbc.com/example.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I try to return an image of its normal size from a facebook post, instead of a thumbnail of 150x150

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535222/get-facebook-real-profile-image-url

Comment: I can return images, but they all come in a reduced size, and "type" parameters just don't work.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do. Could you edit the question and explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
'<img src="'.$mypost['picture'].'" width="400" height="auto">'
```

or

```
'<img src="'.$mypost['picture'].'?width=400" width="400" height="auto">'
```

or

```
'<img src="'.$mypost['picture'].'?type=large" width="400" height="auto">'
```

or just

```
'<img src="'.$mypost['picture'].'?type=large">'
```

Comment: Because images are not always square, they can be portrait-oriented or paysage-oriented, meaning that in one or another case it will be deformed, so I either need to get them in a good size or to detect their original ratio.

Comment: @GrigoryKornilov - You can fix the width or the height. Also, I think you are missing doble quotes for `src`.

Comment: Almost a solution, but the imgae quality is expectably disgusting.

Comment: @GrigoryKornilov - It shouldn't with the two last options.

Comment: Types doesn't work as expected, that's my original surprise. But it seems that it's broken by now (just like some other Graph API functins I've already been to): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982276/facebook-graph-api-change-picture-type-size-no-longer-working?rq=1

Comment: Still the same bad image zoomed in. I tried "redirect=0" as well, as it seems to be related, but it's the same. I guess I will try fql queries, but I have to leave my work now. Still thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that something has changed in Graph API, so the syntax is no more supported: [Facebook Graph API Change: Picture type (size) no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982276/facebook-graph-api-change-picture-type-size-no-longer-working?rq=1)